# Press TAB Key Auto filed next field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

i have a JSf file where multiple text filed. I want when i press "TAB" key next filed with previous filed value.Any help or code material help me thansk in advance.

```
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">             
<h:outputText value="Subno To" />               
</f:facet>
<h:inputText id="mnpSubNoTo_id1" value="#{item.subNoFrom}"/>
</h:column>

<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">             
<h:outputText value="Error Status" />               
</f:facet>
<h:inputText id="mnpErrorStatus_id1" value="#{item.subNoTo}" />
</h:column>
```

i want in this code when in enter text in filed id = "subNoFrom" and press tab next field id="mnpErrorStatus_id1" auto fill with id = "subNoFrom"  field value. 
Any help regarding will be highly appricate!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `onkeydown` event to your first `textbox` as below.

```
<h:inputText id="mnpSubNoTo_id1" value="#{item.subNoFrom}" onkeydown="func(event)"/>
```

Your `javascript` code should be like this.

```
<script>
function func(e) {
    var txt1 = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode
    if(key == 9) {
        var value1 = txt1.value;
        var lastIndex = txt1.id.lastIndexOf(":");
        var txt2Id = txt1.id.substring(0, lastIndex) + ":mnpErrorStatus_id1";
        document.getElementById(txt2Id).value = value1;
    }
}
</script>
```